# Integrate $\frac{1}{e^x} dx$

Tags: integration

$\int{\frac{1}{e^x}} dx$ can be solved by expressing as $\int{e^{-x}}dx$ and using the substitution $u = -x$ for the answer $-\frac{1}{e^x}$.

However, I think this could also be integrated to $\frac{1}{1 - x} e^{(1 - x)}$ using the power rule. Is this also a correct (but sub-optimal) answer, or have I gone wrong somewhere?

Comment: What is the statement of the power rule?  Pay attention to where the variable lives...

Comment: doh... thank you.

Comment: More generally, if you have two functions (say $F$ and $G$), both of which are purported antiderivatives of the same function, then there must be some constant $C$ such that $F = G + C$.  Is it the case that $-\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^x} = \frac{1}{1-x} e^{1-x}$?  If not, then at least one of the two functions is not an antiderivative of $1/\mathrm{e}^x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The power rule doesn't work here.

$$\int \color{blue}{x}^\color{red}{n} \, \mathrm{d}\color{blue}{x} = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} + C \text{ when } n \ne -1$$

whereas

$$\int \color{red}{a}^\color{blue}{x} \, \mathrm{d}\color{blue}{x} = \frac{a^x}{\ln(a)} + C \text{ when } a > 0$$

Notice the issue: the variable you're integrating with respect to is ***not*** in the same place in both expressions. The first has a constant exponent; the second has a constant base.

You can also differentiate your claimed answer to see the problem.